# Lag in Games with Charging

Tags: hardware

So I recently started playing Star Wars Fallen Order with a laptop under the minimum specs. I boot it up and I see a lot of lagging even in Low settings. I turn up my settings to Medium and I disconnect my Charger which I was using and the game was running smoothly in Medium Settings with very little stuttering. Then I put my charger in and it started stuttering again. Could someone tell me why is this happening and how should I play games because these games drain a lot of battery power and I have to connect the charger. Anything would be appreciated

Comment: Have you considered going into your power settings and selecting which mode the laptop should be in based on whether its charging or not? Like, click the battery icon in your taskbar.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that your Laptop turns into "**Low Performance Mode**" while charging it. You should **change that setting** so it's the **same as it is unplugged**.